# Gmsmap view rotation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

In this picture `GMSMapView` has two marker

> 1. Green marker is pickup location and
> 2. Red marker is drop location marker

I want to rotate **mapView** according to pickup location, Pickup location want to start from left side of mapView and drop location want to place in right side of mapView

Rotate : `GMSMapView` using delegate method or any custom methods

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re5Mp.png

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { return self * 180 / .pi }
}
```

In ViewController

```
func getHeadingForDirection(fromCoordinate fromLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D, toCoordinate toLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Float {

let fLat: Float = Float((self.mapView.camera.target.latitude).degreesToRadians)
let fLng: Float = Float((self.mapView.camera.target.longitude).degreesToRadians)
let tLat: Float = Float((fromLoc.latitude).degreesToRadians)
let tLng: Float = Float((fromLoc.longitude).degreesToRadians)
let degree: Float = (atan2(sin(tLng - fLng) * cos(tLat), cos(fLat) * sin(tLat) - sin(fLat) * cos(tLat) * cos(tLng - fLng))).radiansToDegrees
if degree >= 0 {
     return degree
} else {
     return 360 + degree
 }
}
```

In mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition)

```
self.mapView.animate(toBearing: CLLocationDirection((self.getHeadingForDirection(fromCoordinate: self.pickUpMarker.position, toCoordinate: self.dropOffMarker.position) + 100) ))
```